# (LVM) Cannot restore Volume Group with 1 PVs marked as missing. Couldn't find device with uuid, but the pv exists and blkid finds the same uuid

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, lvm, diskmanagement

This problem is on a kvm/qemu hypervisor with CentOS 7, where we host multiple virtual machines.

The Disk /dev/sda( 1918.2 GB) is a raid6 LSI MEGARAID.

```
[root@mia3 ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1918.2 GB, 1918239768576 bytes, 3746562048 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x51549cd4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048   135243775    67108864   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3       135243776   449816575   157286400   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       449816576  3746562047  1648372736   8e  Linux LVM
```

This is our disk configuration:
sda1 - /boot, 
sda2 - swap, 
sda3 - / (root), 
sda4 - PV for our LVM with thin provisioning for our VMs.

After a power failure, our data on the root partition got corrupted. We had to reinstall the OS in order to bring up the server. We didn't touch the /dev/sda4 partition. 
Before that, we mounted the root partition in rescue mode and made a backup for the /etc/lvm/ folder.

After reinstalling Centos we tried to recover LVM using vgcfgrestore, but we got the error:

```
[root@mia3 ~]# vgcfgrestore -f /etc/lvm/backup/vg_kvm vg_kvm -v
    No devices found.
  /dev/sda4: Checksum error at offset 808960
  Couldn't read volume group metadata from /dev/sda4.
  Metadata location on /dev/sda4 at 808960 has invalid summary for VG.
  Failed to read metadata summary from /dev/sda4
  Failed to scan VG from /dev/sda4
  Couldn't find device with uuid HNB35U-ilI4-WWAK-1Q4D-Netj-t68p-Po4vCT.
  Consider using option --force to restore Volume Group vg_kvm with thin volumes.
  Restore failed.
    Scanning all devices to initialize lvmetad.
  /dev/sda4: Checksum error at offset 808960
  Couldn't read volume group metadata from /dev/sda4.
  Metadata location on /dev/sda4 at 808960 has invalid summary for VG.
  Failed to read metadata summary from /dev/sda4
  Failed to scan VG from /dev/sda4
[root@mia3 ~]#
```

So we tried to readd the PV and ovewrite the metadata, but without success:

```
    [root@mia3 ~]# pvcreate -f /dev/sda4 --restorefile /root/lvm/backup/vg_kvm --uuid HNB35U-ilI4-WWAK-1Q4D-Netj-t68p-Po4vCT -vv
      devices/global_filter not found in config: defaulting to global_filter = [ "a|.*/|" ]
      global/lvmetad_update_wait_time not found in config: defaulting to 10
      devices/filter not found in config: defaulting to filter = [ "a|.*/|" ]
      devices/cache not found in config: defaulting to /etc/lvm/cache/.cache
      metadata/record_lvs_history not found in config: defaulting to 0
      File-based locking selected.
  Couldn't find device with uuid HNB35U-ilI4-WWAK-1Q4D-Netj-t68p-Po4vCT.
      Stack vg_kvm/lvpool:0[0] on LV vg_kvm/lvpool_tdata:0.
      Adding vg_kvm/lvpool:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool_tdata.
      Adding vg_kvm/lvpool:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool_tmeta.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv11999-dm9oryxunpw8po9p-1xwrkrotul6i5k3g:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12001-dmzdbquhkhrydlnf-kqjcbeyvz1c5xwun:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12034-dnadddzaxsxoq2rx-iwxjz6wr2vmqhsj3:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12036-dbgt9zilw2tg9sqd-c0xa9h1uxigjuqg9:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12037-dctrjirji3agbl9l-dtzyf8jrb8lip0m7:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12038-dm5mulwohkvz5ara-kccgnknpjdi11tdy:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12039-d1lnb9qcyjaqmodk-mnl22loaflo24kpm:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12040-daejvderic4uvccj-wjnydccgzohyaekq:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12046-dswief4uk4gthxa1-ie5s7up6vbf37p68:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12056-du7hvvsp3lw7jgja-uap8l1jpe29llrpu:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12080-dwydbngcjptnnryn-hzz0jimwfl6yau2x:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12094-d8cmko7aio2f1fyo-warkvewdzfeedme5:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12097-dllp7oepp4homdj9-jm6n2itmvy29k9xf:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12098-dcj6mnnidej8c80u-r3bkk3pfu8g9sf3o:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12103-dwtyfq1quemcij56-4rwivmmtzxwk1ydb:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12106-dngrxbyoapwac5sm-bstrvsbxzrztefob:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12107-dq3h0wgnzkasoles-hv12r8qmyobojubp:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12109-ddq6cmtow9qwuaka-v9a1omyljy0xujk4:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12110-dvaaktx2bng99yl9-f5xh28mlg7u3mo5r:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12111-db0wlufykbcbb2mp-dxhgxxmivthvqwwp:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12112-dyfnblgyajfpidqs-ny0xpnxhzfzwc1db:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12116-dowxexkxa0ygsgki-e4dih6xcnybtdgx2:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12117-dwd0weu8ig1dvukx-fly3n8dyseklhntv:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12118-dz9hbvnbtsihufm5-paqhexr1tuld8bnd:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12119-dof5n90vez6smo1j-h1xmccyzl7qotery:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12120-d9q0y85z4shpw64o-6zx5tmxhajpcxtkv:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12121-dac4vuig8akyryd0-0e4rf2snm04r5mdy:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12122-d99yza6ssbhxxkru-16ptyp8btexq6wkb:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12124-d4ud5tu2ueajr0vc-r9pv77cjusnjue21:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12126-dqjmtfzubhqvheij-blecac71kpwsmy62:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12127-d5sgcmdodjaqtvp9-oqbroobow5tzn0va:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12130-dtf7rf4suf8bov9t-8lb0agstvcpann2e:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12131-dwkveordvertdam3-3g4qwtf5ydhy0hug:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12134-dgpxbewt3xlkxlqb-j5ad04pt2fndqqmw:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12135-d55krjg3dotss3e4-dwbbjmo0shwwwzv2:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12138-dyz9yl6swxbaxfrj-1pgri05suzqyagqq:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12140-dykgcwqaauznoxrm-4ibft4womwuvpwkx:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12142-dwtlkzoke0a05u1o-rqxjogzuvjvfttxs:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12144-dn3gyu3uroppwgzg-wraejm2ynwnmtmd4:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12162-dalw90et3l9vbath-eo5womktdromb5sn:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12211-dyyizuuag0mz4eok-je7du6slil1jlfzp:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12329-d5xmlj2iqsuekgkm-cg6qplkwk48yiyeo:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12333-drqvvb7fktr4n52b-estbavvooqdljpvo:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12334-dbdf0lvefbgpqbxa-bmpnzainjdfvuavv:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12339-d3yfeg1upsfoxbd3-nbxbccudjdtcgztt:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12354-d1ctzl88dwv9znri-pzfp6weunhpdhvgn:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12361-dbug4gr7r8mbsnva-yamgras92xuqin66:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12088-dqphwqqeuwxtmm7y-4rurc6jm0lvcj57q:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12089-dbhimrcqvjkaxvxc-3vpljlh2xkojhb9e:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12090-dndlzsmpj8qgm2gb-wm4sg3d6n2cq3tpm:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12091-dyyxcz5cf4w4cu6z-gja2kph6egpjvyzh:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12092-dnllln6x7uud75ss-um9zelymhc04ohd6:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12442-dyf2cgwdgaluli0s-cahwc74lrstt61gl:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12456-dmiuo7guhru4snsf-yt55qun0wx5mtfkg:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12087-dxbtb8w1g3tx5akk-bdqcsnlathemkrig:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12234-dq82wyoapvxvh7zz-maaekbfd7h9ixks8:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12588-das5kos8qt1ziktl-aky0pxwg8ecv9b48:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12771-djaikmniei1vxia5-jhqasdwc763s3pmb:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12784-d3k6aplejbvjrlcw-uwo81r0wkmeiptso:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12139-dpnhdmg2odfabvfn-zqgiw42wfsgbbkrc:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12137-dxtiqptvdwcrrcwa-22fkxorf6hl44evf:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12866-d37htmu48aopiafv-sli9m0lt3dz0yeyl:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12096-dz9pfno05wqq8vbg-sq8i5na5z8lrnm6n:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12363-dtlh9w3tza99quoj-dlicfndz6e3pbfu0:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12890-dmaaydjldw3c13jk-iskdygh5pczveo3r:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12320-dqmecms9nep6muns-xmmkziafa8mz1hta:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12936-dhdfa36ovcdzfafp-ultnlmom4scugsw1:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12964-dctbp9xgo2gl8w6i-kbw9cinhoieea8av:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12984-dwqjvkqc3aznhb4o-criyexpxvdndoscq:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12143-d3s1toagczaiq4ma-oupwnk3eg27r41ze:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13019-d5yrsi5a58bdzalc-i6mbum8zthk2arhs:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13022-djszrasae5w7xegh-ehqsutbhrwd7qgsi:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13027-dq6pg99jd2fphljg-u15x8sonbwukaree:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12041-dlsmtmfa6fp4wcuc-bfhftkdhwfqa7sqb:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13039-djtjimojqi3iaufp-csbinqtsvebzzmqx:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13061-duocptl9qdtvwubp-feryqeejht4j24ql:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13064-dexwkomdh62by80s-aymbuetu6p0btn4d:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13076-drd4nrhy4u7fq1tn-f1kt8ubk2jch4ol3:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13082-ds9gjikqyg9nftua-rrhk4dlrr8cp3la7:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12759-du4yducr4ghi8eun-bzivqxabwaltaddm:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12123-dzb9rktypp0jqinx-adtlzed02wpccxoa:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13118-d0lj9gpvqfmox63i-9jstjcjkmemszrla:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13121-du0r39n6wvnrclox-bviz76ig9vvexota:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13133-d2fk6lg6bsppbkcs-hwk5bmsvqxa0y0bs:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13204-dl6hzsmswetitsb4-bais6lpjbbhfkexn:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13230-dtiyrmijg8mde5xy-vobukov1qxg8bx5j:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13254-d3sdhrrgcvbwrsyp-yxaozxmt3clqzxxc:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13271-drutw4ihq774xhs6-ecpwfmzcrqy0vvsm:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13266-dmuj5cfeu2hrgfxw-2tpflycnwoedyidb:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13380-d99ciziibe7rt3es-7fkh56myy79oushw:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13487-d30yxx4wgfxcb9te-chc2bxojs7tvcwz3:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13502-dc2oivdodzo94jj3-1qmpba9ti4zzbfeg:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13277-deudjco25w9cd3rv-re1ha5qkozses9i3:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12208-dfqhoqmtuwzktwqm-n9s5daovhtnyvyeh:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13481-dthcwgpolombhfed-dkmesvsvmt1vem0d:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13585-ddvwhm2vcqpq66uy-1brs98bctgr6bcq9:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13586-dadacaexxn8nkuy3-fyx8zp5mursbqhns:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13587-dc0fmskwdbkmz7mg-ra53wgfksiv7tsqk:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13569-dk6v0pyvz8eoohl5-qyndiwn8zriir75s:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13603-d66mz2amabmd63fj-rkcqmtvfnlfmywou:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13613-dykuo32mnkgf9nce-hhkhn118dhsedoc8:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13623-dksoizdtoglihaax-23o0zltutliyoo2q:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13629-dxbpqqernfvufxrz-iv6jujdxm78hxjbn:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13610-drrehnh36oipacdf-frnumdhlt823mntg:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13654-dmlnhhqilztxff5a-4gawkysgtkze4st7:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13669-dk3ukgidvj0l4x4x-9d3vfao5qejzecdn:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13672-d1r1608gu96b0ujo-nn7ejmxkbfce40m4:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13689-dhpzh8w7jlwi0zza-aqizb6tbeuk9k1ca:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12477-dejmu0gihtllnj97-gaxwgicndwp25unx:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13710-dv2bktawped5fz44-0bkdtrkp8tk2vynu:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12125-d5d9pebts1rue7jt-vwnkapewjkfszked:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13718-dmimkn9h1ax3t4am-8tdnpznya2reek8g:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13545-dzaq2rjqfiyf5azl-kw35xomndhltjnrs:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13723-daleipfjwu7zm7aj-s8jo6yhxwz4efl2y:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13726-dpdqvmnzkvxkiz4y-cfudhed6m12hnlmj:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12136-d0qvvamyx5qq1g6o-awtlh6pbotvlacyc:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13258-du2kuwgkwhypcfzz-i6h00rd0exzw4b69:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13755-dqglblzy3akyohph-wtev5tlrs5lkkejd:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13758-dhfrybljxildcky1-ktotkou3mpvxfjnq:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13759-dxqbq7phpjgoa1ed-dwtly1dkuorvlyli:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13762-di54bo3us4p8gefa-34s2uhcye1rbdbvw:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13767-dwtsyqxhqbp8fa9w-us8xvwm9q6nqkmzx:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13768-dadnlkrau2cwhlbd-cj8liz4hfolpmjfa:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13769-dt4nwlcmpfqyenob-jvpfd5jut8kvcm8u:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13781-dvckr0uqfwrsvmc6-zklf1olhlhzzfppp:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12133-dp55dttaolpbd6n8-rlhoezgituqkyrov:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12042-dnncyzlyhfxyaxkt-metx0ei0zlz3d2sn:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      metadata/pvmetadataignore not found in config: defaulting to 0
      metadata/pvmetadatasize not found in config: defaulting to 255
      metadata/pvmetadatacopies not found in config: defaulting to 1
      report/output_format not found in config: defaulting to basic
      log/report_command_log not found in config: defaulting to 0
      Locking /run/lock/lvm/P_orphans WB
      /dev/sda4: size is 3296745472 sectors
      /dev/sda4: using cached size 3296745472 sectors
      /dev/sda: size is 3746562048 sectors
      /dev/sda1: size is 1024000 sectors
      /dev/sda1: using cached size 1024000 sectors
      /dev/sda2: size is 134217728 sectors
      /dev/sda2: using cached size 134217728 sectors
      /dev/sda3: size is 314572800 sectors
      /dev/sda3: using cached size 314572800 sectors
      /dev/sda4: using cached size 3296745472 sectors
      /dev/sda4: using cached size 3296745472 sectors
      Locking #orphans_lvm1 already done
      Reading VG #orphans_lvm1
      Locking #orphans_pool already done
      Reading VG #orphans_pool
      Locking #orphans_lvm2 already done
      Reading VG #orphans_lvm2
      Processing device /dev/sda1.
      Processing device /dev/sda2.
      Processing device /dev/sda3.
      Processing device /dev/sda4.
      /dev/sda4: lvm2 label detected at sector 1
  /dev/sda4: Checksum error at offset 808960
  Couldn't read volume group metadata from /dev/sda4.
  Metadata location on /dev/sda4 at 808960 has invalid summary for VG.
  Failed to read metadata summary from /dev/sda4
  Failed to scan VG from /dev/sda4
      Unlocking /run/lock/lvm/P_orphans
[root@mia3 ~]#
```

Note the error:

```
  Couldn't find device with uuid HNB35U-ilI4-WWAK-1Q4D-Netj-t68p-Po4vCT.
```

The PV (/dev/sda4) has the same UUID:

```
[root@mia3 ~]# blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="boot" UUID="087755bd-9434-4597-953b-c056fd9cb285" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="swap" UUID="c7fd2030-0441-4a4e-8462-0aeffc272bfa" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="root" UUID="3ee19cf6-87b5-40b5-a7dd-13d507efa734" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/sda4: UUID="HNB35U-ilI4-WWAK-1Q4D-Netj-t68p-Po4vCT" TYPE="LVM2_member"
[root@mia3 ~]#
```

Here is a small part of the content for /etc/lvm/backup/vg_kvm:

```
vg_kvm {
    id = "i3usZz-vdt5-9yaU-Kbcl-XDWJ-OFr1-UhZRBa"
    seqno = 1349
    format = "lvm2"                 # informational
    status = ["RESIZEABLE", "READ", "WRITE"]
    flags = []
    extent_size = 8192              # 4 Megabytes
    max_lv = 0
    max_pv = 0
    metadata_copies = 0

    physical_volumes {

            pv0 {
                    id = "HNB35U-ilI4-WWAK-1Q4D-Netj-t68p-Po4vCT"
                    device = "/dev/sda4"    # Hint only

                    status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
                    flags = []
                    dev_size = 3296745472   # 1.53517 Terabytes
                    pe_start = 2048
                    pe_count = 402434       # 1.53516 Terabytes
            }
    }

    logical_volumes {

            lvpool {
                    id = "DHqs7X-95DA-ADNm-WTd9-cXDf-HR5a-MoHLRx"
                    status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
                    flags = []
                    creation_time = 1575901618      # 2019-12-09 16:26:58 +0200
                    creation_host = "mia3"
                    segment_count = 1

                    segment1 {
                            start_extent = 0
                            extent_count = 401081   # 1.53 Terabytes

                            type = "thin-pool"
                            metadata = "lvpool_tmeta"
                            pool = "lvpool_tdata"
                            transaction_id = 667
                            chunk_size = 2048       # 1024 Kilobytes
                            discards = "passdown"
                            zero_new_blocks = 1
                    }
            }

            vsv11999-dm9oryxunpw8po9p-1xwrkrotul6i5k3g {
                    id = "vBco77-gPno-S0cu-QZdx-9Nnk-twXR-cBBAzW"
                    status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
                    flags = []
                    creation_time = 1575902920      # 2019-12-09 16:48:40 +0200
                    creation_host = "mia3"
                    segment_count = 1

                    segment1 {
                            start_extent = 0
                            extent_count = 6400     # 25 Gigabytes

                            type = "thin"
                            thin_pool = "lvpool"
                            transaction_id = 0
                            device_id = 1
                    }
            }

            vsv12001-dmzdbquhkhrydlnf-kqjcbeyvz1c5xwun {
                    id = "xqDzS2-iHXO-2zEi-LRHO-0FDR-hvcM-oRdFeD"
                    status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
                    flags = []
                    creation_time = 1575904408      # 2019-12-09 17:13:28 +0200
                    creation_host = "mia3"
                    segment_count = 1

                    segment1 {
                            start_extent = 0
                            extent_count = 3840     # 15 Gigabytes

                            type = "thin"
                            thin_pool = "lvpool"
                            transaction_id = 1
                            device_id = 2
                    }
            }

            vsv12034-dnadddzaxsxoq2rx-iwxjz6wr2vmqhsj3 {
                    id = "VIDuPN-SN4Z-V1qm-gzI9-sSnV-WGcp-NBvgUa"
                    status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
                    flags = []
                    creation_time = 1575986509      # 2019-12-10 16:01:49 +0200
                    creation_host = "mia3"
                    segment_count = 1

                    segment1 {
                            start_extent = 0
                            extent_count = 3840     # 15 Gigabytes

                            type = "thin"
                            thin_pool = "lvpool"
                            transaction_id = 6
                            device_id = 5
                    }
            }

            vsv12036-dbgt9zilw2tg9sqd-c0xa9h1uxigjuqg9 {
                    id = "XnnwPm-e3jE-VU9W-7QIz-3Sz5-HDSM-sEe7NY"
                    status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
                    flags = []
                    creation_time = 1575988785      # 2019-12-10 16:39:45 +0200
                    creation_host = "mia3"
                    segment_count = 1

                    segment1 {
                            start_extent = 0
                            extent_count = 3840     # 15 Gigabytes

                            type = "thin"
                            thin_pool = "lvpool"
                            transaction_id = 8
                            device_id = 7
                    }
            }

            vsv12037-dctrjirji3agbl9l-dtzyf8jrb8lip0m7 {
                    id = "ysHM90-Vmof-Mrwj-Nb1s-HPER-g3v5-hdutBz"
                    status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
                    flags = []
                    creation_time = 1575989058      # 2019-12-10 16:44:18 +0200
                    creation_host = "mia3"
                    segment_count = 1

                    segment1 {
                            start_extent = 0
                            extent_count = 3840     # 15 Gigabytes

                            type = "thin"
                            thin_pool = "lvpool"
                            transaction_id = 9
                            device_id = 8
                    }
            }
```

All the data (root partitions for our VMs) are still there, we have checked with disk recovery tools like testdisk, but we can't recover the lvm.
What are we doing wrong? Is there a possibility of recovering?

#

UPDATE

Using Centos6 CD and rescue mode I have managed to restore the PV and VG. However, I can't reactivate the VG and LV pool, we're getting the error:

```
 Executing: /usr/sbin/thin_check -q --clear-needs-check-flag /dev/mapper/vg_kvm-lvpool_tmeta
/usr/sbin/thin_check failed: 1
Check of pool vg_kvm/lvpool failed (status:1). Manual repair required!
```

Comment: I'm sure you are way past this, but have you tried "pvscan -ay" to rescan /dev/sda4 as a physical volumes?

Comment: [root@mia3 ~]# pvscan --cache -aay -v
    Scanning all devices.
    Scanning all devices to initialize lvmetad.
  /dev/sda4: Checksum error at offset 808960
  Couldn't read volume group metadata from /dev/sda4.
  Metadata location on /dev/sda4 at 808960 has invalid summary for VG.
  Failed to read metadata summary from /dev/sda4
  Failed to scan VG from /dev/sda4
    No volume groups found.
[root@mia3 ~]#

Comment: [In a related question](https://serverfault.com/q/499300/31475), I found that LVM doesn't scan for multipath devices by default? Apparently you can alter the filter it searches for in `/etc/lvm.conf`. Note: I once had a server that inexplicably had the devices configured as multipath. Edit: BTW: are you in a position to `dd` the whole partition somewhere else, over ssh or something, as backup?

Comment: I have added the filter "filter = [ "a|/dev/sda.*|", "a|/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-.*mpath-.*|", "r|.*|"]" but the errors are unchanged. EDIT: I do not have where to DD the partition at the moment unfortunately.

Comment: @Halfgaar it's a good idea to clear the lvm headers using "dd if=/dev/zero bs=1k count=10 of=/dev/sda4"" and try restoring PVs by running pvcreate with the "--uuid" and "--restorefile" ? Is there any chance to overwrite & lose my existing data?

Comment: @cdgmn you can always lose your data :). Other than that, I've never tried such recovery. But, if you're only going to overwrite the first few MBs, at least backup that bit with DD. If you do `dd if=/dev/sda4 of=/somewere/backup-first100MB.img bs=1M count=100`, you at least have that segment. However, a full `dd` to some disk as backup would be very useful before you start experimenting.

Comment: As a response to your answer which should have been an edit. It says: 'thin_check_executable not found'. Do you have `/usr/sbin/thin_check`? Perhaps booting an old system is not as smart as a new sysrescuecd. Also, you're not saying if that error came from CentOS 6, or when booting back to CentOS 7.

Comment: @Halfgaar the error appeared after booting back to CentOS 7. [root@mia3 ~]# whereis thin_check
thin_check: /usr/sbin/thin_check /usr/share/man/man8/thin_check.8.gz
[root@mia3 ~]#

Comment: And sysrescuecd boot USB? BTW, also that info you can add to your original question by editing. Also, if you have working LVM _somewhere_, I'd `dd` the indivdual LVMs somewhere, and you can manually `dd` them into new empty volumes of the same size. As a last resort.

Comment: The same error for when activating vg or lv ... no matter the os I am trying on. The DD will not work because the LV's are not active..

Answer (score 1):

It appears Red Hat 7 and 8 have similar issues when trying to use `vgcfgrestore`: [The pvcreate command fails with "Metadata location has invalid summary for VG" error](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1660625) . CentOS shares a base with Red Hat, so...

One answer there was "We have a solution for this problem upstream and in RHEL8, Unfortunately, it is too invasive to consider back porting to RHEL7 at this stage." Another person in that bug said they fixed it by booting Red Hat 6, and then `vgcfgrestore` worked.

Perhaps you can boot a new sysrescue CD from a USB stick and do it?

And as I said in a comment, either backup the whole volume with `dd`, or at least do something like `dd if=/dev/sda4 of=/somewere/backup-first100MB.img bs=1M count=100` so that you have the header info.

Comment: Thanks, I have started backing up the whole sda4 disk on a remote server. After that, I'll try both with rescue & centos 6 and also overwriting the first few MBs.

Answer (score 1):

It worked with Centos6 rescue. After restoring, I booted into normal centos 7 and the vg was there. However, now I can't activate the lv (thin pool):

```
[root@mia3 ~]# lvchange -ay /dev/vg_kvm/lvpool
  Check of pool vg_kvm/lvpool failed (status:1). Manual repair required!
[root@mia3 ~]#
```

Here is the command again with -vvv

```
    [root@mia3 ~]# lvchange -ay /dev/vg_kvm/lvpool -vv
      devices/global_filter not found in config: defaulting to global_filter = [ "a|.*/|" ]
      global/lvmetad_update_wait_time not found in config: defaulting to 10
      Setting devices/filter to filter = [ "a|/dev/sda.*|", "a|/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-.*mpath-.*|", "r|.*|" ]
      devices/cache not found in config: defaulting to /etc/lvm/cache/.cache
      metadata/record_lvs_history not found in config: defaulting to 0
      File-based locking selected.
      report/output_format not found in config: defaulting to basic
      log/report_command_log not found in config: defaulting to 0
      Obtaining the complete list of VGs before processing their LVs
      Processing VG vg_kvm i3usZz-vdt5-9yaU-Kbcl-XDWJ-OFr1-UhZRBa
      Locking /run/lock/lvm/V_vg_kvm RB
      Reading VG vg_kvm i3usZz-vdt5-9yaU-Kbcl-XDWJ-OFr1-UhZRBa
      Stack vg_kvm/lvpool:0[0] on LV vg_kvm/lvpool_tdata:0.
      Adding vg_kvm/lvpool:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool_tdata.
      Adding vg_kvm/lvpool:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool_tmeta.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv11999-dm9oryxunpw8po9p-1xwrkrotul6i5k3g:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12001-dmzdbquhkhrydlnf-kqjcbeyvz1c5xwun:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12034-dnadddzaxsxoq2rx-iwxjz6wr2vmqhsj3:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12036-dbgt9zilw2tg9sqd-c0xa9h1uxigjuqg9:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12037-dctrjirji3agbl9l-dtzyf8jrb8lip0m7:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12038-dm5mulwohkvz5ara-kccgnknpjdi11tdy:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12039-d1lnb9qcyjaqmodk-mnl22loaflo24kpm:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12040-daejvderic4uvccj-wjnydccgzohyaekq:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12046-dswief4uk4gthxa1-ie5s7up6vbf37p68:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12056-du7hvvsp3lw7jgja-uap8l1jpe29llrpu:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12080-dwydbngcjptnnryn-hzz0jimwfl6yau2x:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12094-d8cmko7aio2f1fyo-warkvewdzfeedme5:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12097-dllp7oepp4homdj9-jm6n2itmvy29k9xf:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12098-dcj6mnnidej8c80u-r3bkk3pfu8g9sf3o:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12103-dwtyfq1quemcij56-4rwivmmtzxwk1ydb:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12106-dngrxbyoapwac5sm-bstrvsbxzrztefob:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12107-dq3h0wgnzkasoles-hv12r8qmyobojubp:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12109-ddq6cmtow9qwuaka-v9a1omyljy0xujk4:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12110-dvaaktx2bng99yl9-f5xh28mlg7u3mo5r:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12111-db0wlufykbcbb2mp-dxhgxxmivthvqwwp:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12112-dyfnblgyajfpidqs-ny0xpnxhzfzwc1db:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12116-dowxexkxa0ygsgki-e4dih6xcnybtdgx2:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12117-dwd0weu8ig1dvukx-fly3n8dyseklhntv:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12118-dz9hbvnbtsihufm5-paqhexr1tuld8bnd:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12119-dof5n90vez6smo1j-h1xmccyzl7qotery:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12120-d9q0y85z4shpw64o-6zx5tmxhajpcxtkv:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12121-dac4vuig8akyryd0-0e4rf2snm04r5mdy:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12122-d99yza6ssbhxxkru-16ptyp8btexq6wkb:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12124-d4ud5tu2ueajr0vc-r9pv77cjusnjue21:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12126-dqjmtfzubhqvheij-blecac71kpwsmy62:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12127-d5sgcmdodjaqtvp9-oqbroobow5tzn0va:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12130-dtf7rf4suf8bov9t-8lb0agstvcpann2e:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12131-dwkveordvertdam3-3g4qwtf5ydhy0hug:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12134-dgpxbewt3xlkxlqb-j5ad04pt2fndqqmw:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12135-d55krjg3dotss3e4-dwbbjmo0shwwwzv2:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12138-dyz9yl6swxbaxfrj-1pgri05suzqyagqq:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12140-dykgcwqaauznoxrm-4ibft4womwuvpwkx:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12142-dwtlkzoke0a05u1o-rqxjogzuvjvfttxs:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12144-dn3gyu3uroppwgzg-wraejm2ynwnmtmd4:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12162-dalw90et3l9vbath-eo5womktdromb5sn:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12211-dyyizuuag0mz4eok-je7du6slil1jlfzp:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12329-d5xmlj2iqsuekgkm-cg6qplkwk48yiyeo:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12333-drqvvb7fktr4n52b-estbavvooqdljpvo:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12334-dbdf0lvefbgpqbxa-bmpnzainjdfvuavv:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12339-d3yfeg1upsfoxbd3-nbxbccudjdtcgztt:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12354-d1ctzl88dwv9znri-pzfp6weunhpdhvgn:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12361-dbug4gr7r8mbsnva-yamgras92xuqin66:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12088-dqphwqqeuwxtmm7y-4rurc6jm0lvcj57q:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12089-dbhimrcqvjkaxvxc-3vpljlh2xkojhb9e:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12090-dndlzsmpj8qgm2gb-wm4sg3d6n2cq3tpm:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12091-dyyxcz5cf4w4cu6z-gja2kph6egpjvyzh:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12092-dnllln6x7uud75ss-um9zelymhc04ohd6:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12442-dyf2cgwdgaluli0s-cahwc74lrstt61gl:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12456-dmiuo7guhru4snsf-yt55qun0wx5mtfkg:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12087-dxbtb8w1g3tx5akk-bdqcsnlathemkrig:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12234-dq82wyoapvxvh7zz-maaekbfd7h9ixks8:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12588-das5kos8qt1ziktl-aky0pxwg8ecv9b48:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12771-djaikmniei1vxia5-jhqasdwc763s3pmb:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12784-d3k6aplejbvjrlcw-uwo81r0wkmeiptso:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12139-dpnhdmg2odfabvfn-zqgiw42wfsgbbkrc:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12137-dxtiqptvdwcrrcwa-22fkxorf6hl44evf:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12866-d37htmu48aopiafv-sli9m0lt3dz0yeyl:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12096-dz9pfno05wqq8vbg-sq8i5na5z8lrnm6n:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12363-dtlh9w3tza99quoj-dlicfndz6e3pbfu0:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12890-dmaaydjldw3c13jk-iskdygh5pczveo3r:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12320-dqmecms9nep6muns-xmmkziafa8mz1hta:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12936-dhdfa36ovcdzfafp-ultnlmom4scugsw1:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12964-dctbp9xgo2gl8w6i-kbw9cinhoieea8av:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12984-dwqjvkqc3aznhb4o-criyexpxvdndoscq:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12143-d3s1toagczaiq4ma-oupwnk3eg27r41ze:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13019-d5yrsi5a58bdzalc-i6mbum8zthk2arhs:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13022-djszrasae5w7xegh-ehqsutbhrwd7qgsi:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13027-dq6pg99jd2fphljg-u15x8sonbwukaree:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12041-dlsmtmfa6fp4wcuc-bfhftkdhwfqa7sqb:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13039-djtjimojqi3iaufp-csbinqtsvebzzmqx:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13061-duocptl9qdtvwubp-feryqeejht4j24ql:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13064-dexwkomdh62by80s-aymbuetu6p0btn4d:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13076-drd4nrhy4u7fq1tn-f1kt8ubk2jch4ol3:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13082-ds9gjikqyg9nftua-rrhk4dlrr8cp3la7:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12759-du4yducr4ghi8eun-bzivqxabwaltaddm:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12123-dzb9rktypp0jqinx-adtlzed02wpccxoa:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13118-d0lj9gpvqfmox63i-9jstjcjkmemszrla:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13121-du0r39n6wvnrclox-bviz76ig9vvexota:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13133-d2fk6lg6bsppbkcs-hwk5bmsvqxa0y0bs:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13204-dl6hzsmswetitsb4-bais6lpjbbhfkexn:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13230-dtiyrmijg8mde5xy-vobukov1qxg8bx5j:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13254-d3sdhrrgcvbwrsyp-yxaozxmt3clqzxxc:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13271-drutw4ihq774xhs6-ecpwfmzcrqy0vvsm:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13266-dmuj5cfeu2hrgfxw-2tpflycnwoedyidb:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13380-d99ciziibe7rt3es-7fkh56myy79oushw:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13487-d30yxx4wgfxcb9te-chc2bxojs7tvcwz3:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13502-dc2oivdodzo94jj3-1qmpba9ti4zzbfeg:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13277-deudjco25w9cd3rv-re1ha5qkozses9i3:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12208-dfqhoqmtuwzktwqm-n9s5daovhtnyvyeh:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13481-dthcwgpolombhfed-dkmesvsvmt1vem0d:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13585-ddvwhm2vcqpq66uy-1brs98bctgr6bcq9:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13586-dadacaexxn8nkuy3-fyx8zp5mursbqhns:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13587-dc0fmskwdbkmz7mg-ra53wgfksiv7tsqk:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13569-dk6v0pyvz8eoohl5-qyndiwn8zriir75s:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13603-d66mz2amabmd63fj-rkcqmtvfnlfmywou:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13613-dykuo32mnkgf9nce-hhkhn118dhsedoc8:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13623-dksoizdtoglihaax-23o0zltutliyoo2q:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13629-dxbpqqernfvufxrz-iv6jujdxm78hxjbn:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13610-drrehnh36oipacdf-frnumdhlt823mntg:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13654-dmlnhhqilztxff5a-4gawkysgtkze4st7:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13669-dk3ukgidvj0l4x4x-9d3vfao5qejzecdn:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13672-d1r1608gu96b0ujo-nn7ejmxkbfce40m4:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13689-dhpzh8w7jlwi0zza-aqizb6tbeuk9k1ca:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12477-dejmu0gihtllnj97-gaxwgicndwp25unx:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13710-dv2bktawped5fz44-0bkdtrkp8tk2vynu:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12125-d5d9pebts1rue7jt-vwnkapewjkfszked:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13718-dmimkn9h1ax3t4am-8tdnpznya2reek8g:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13545-dzaq2rjqfiyf5azl-kw35xomndhltjnrs:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13723-daleipfjwu7zm7aj-s8jo6yhxwz4efl2y:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13726-dpdqvmnzkvxkiz4y-cfudhed6m12hnlmj:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12136-d0qvvamyx5qq1g6o-awtlh6pbotvlacyc:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13258-du2kuwgkwhypcfzz-i6h00rd0exzw4b69:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13755-dqglblzy3akyohph-wtev5tlrs5lkkejd:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13758-dhfrybljxildcky1-ktotkou3mpvxfjnq:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13759-dxqbq7phpjgoa1ed-dwtly1dkuorvlyli:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13762-di54bo3us4p8gefa-34s2uhcye1rbdbvw:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13767-dwtsyqxhqbp8fa9w-us8xvwm9q6nqkmzx:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13768-dadnlkrau2cwhlbd-cj8liz4hfolpmjfa:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13769-dt4nwlcmpfqyenob-jvpfd5jut8kvcm8u:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv13781-dvckr0uqfwrsvmc6-zklf1olhlhzzfppp:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12133-dp55dttaolpbd6n8-rlhoezgituqkyrov:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      Adding vg_kvm/vsv12042-dnncyzlyhfxyaxkt-metx0ei0zlz3d2sn:0 as an user of vg_kvm/lvpool.
      /dev/sda4: size is 3296745472 sectors
      Adding vg_kvm/lvpool to the list of LVs to be processed.
      Processing LV lvpool in VG vg_kvm.
    Activating logical volume vg_kvm/lvpool exclusively.
      Locking /run/lock/lvm/A_vg_kvm WB
      vg_kvm/lvpool is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv11999-dm9oryxunpw8po9p-1xwrkrotul6i5k3g is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12001-dmzdbquhkhrydlnf-kqjcbeyvz1c5xwun is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12034-dnadddzaxsxoq2rx-iwxjz6wr2vmqhsj3 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12036-dbgt9zilw2tg9sqd-c0xa9h1uxigjuqg9 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12037-dctrjirji3agbl9l-dtzyf8jrb8lip0m7 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12038-dm5mulwohkvz5ara-kccgnknpjdi11tdy is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12039-d1lnb9qcyjaqmodk-mnl22loaflo24kpm is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12040-daejvderic4uvccj-wjnydccgzohyaekq is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12046-dswief4uk4gthxa1-ie5s7up6vbf37p68 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12056-du7hvvsp3lw7jgja-uap8l1jpe29llrpu is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12080-dwydbngcjptnnryn-hzz0jimwfl6yau2x is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12094-d8cmko7aio2f1fyo-warkvewdzfeedme5 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12097-dllp7oepp4homdj9-jm6n2itmvy29k9xf is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12098-dcj6mnnidej8c80u-r3bkk3pfu8g9sf3o is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12103-dwtyfq1quemcij56-4rwivmmtzxwk1ydb is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12106-dngrxbyoapwac5sm-bstrvsbxzrztefob is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12107-dq3h0wgnzkasoles-hv12r8qmyobojubp is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12109-ddq6cmtow9qwuaka-v9a1omyljy0xujk4 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12110-dvaaktx2bng99yl9-f5xh28mlg7u3mo5r is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12111-db0wlufykbcbb2mp-dxhgxxmivthvqwwp is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12112-dyfnblgyajfpidqs-ny0xpnxhzfzwc1db is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12116-dowxexkxa0ygsgki-e4dih6xcnybtdgx2 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12117-dwd0weu8ig1dvukx-fly3n8dyseklhntv is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12118-dz9hbvnbtsihufm5-paqhexr1tuld8bnd is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12119-dof5n90vez6smo1j-h1xmccyzl7qotery is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12120-d9q0y85z4shpw64o-6zx5tmxhajpcxtkv is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12121-dac4vuig8akyryd0-0e4rf2snm04r5mdy is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12122-d99yza6ssbhxxkru-16ptyp8btexq6wkb is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12124-d4ud5tu2ueajr0vc-r9pv77cjusnjue21 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12126-dqjmtfzubhqvheij-blecac71kpwsmy62 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12127-d5sgcmdodjaqtvp9-oqbroobow5tzn0va is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12130-dtf7rf4suf8bov9t-8lb0agstvcpann2e is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12131-dwkveordvertdam3-3g4qwtf5ydhy0hug is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12134-dgpxbewt3xlkxlqb-j5ad04pt2fndqqmw is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12135-d55krjg3dotss3e4-dwbbjmo0shwwwzv2 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12138-dyz9yl6swxbaxfrj-1pgri05suzqyagqq is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12140-dykgcwqaauznoxrm-4ibft4womwuvpwkx is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12142-dwtlkzoke0a05u1o-rqxjogzuvjvfttxs is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12144-dn3gyu3uroppwgzg-wraejm2ynwnmtmd4 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12162-dalw90et3l9vbath-eo5womktdromb5sn is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12211-dyyizuuag0mz4eok-je7du6slil1jlfzp is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12329-d5xmlj2iqsuekgkm-cg6qplkwk48yiyeo is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12333-drqvvb7fktr4n52b-estbavvooqdljpvo is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12334-dbdf0lvefbgpqbxa-bmpnzainjdfvuavv is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12339-d3yfeg1upsfoxbd3-nbxbccudjdtcgztt is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12354-d1ctzl88dwv9znri-pzfp6weunhpdhvgn is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12361-dbug4gr7r8mbsnva-yamgras92xuqin66 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12088-dqphwqqeuwxtmm7y-4rurc6jm0lvcj57q is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12089-dbhimrcqvjkaxvxc-3vpljlh2xkojhb9e is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12090-dndlzsmpj8qgm2gb-wm4sg3d6n2cq3tpm is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12091-dyyxcz5cf4w4cu6z-gja2kph6egpjvyzh is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12092-dnllln6x7uud75ss-um9zelymhc04ohd6 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12442-dyf2cgwdgaluli0s-cahwc74lrstt61gl is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12456-dmiuo7guhru4snsf-yt55qun0wx5mtfkg is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12087-dxbtb8w1g3tx5akk-bdqcsnlathemkrig is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12234-dq82wyoapvxvh7zz-maaekbfd7h9ixks8 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12588-das5kos8qt1ziktl-aky0pxwg8ecv9b48 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12771-djaikmniei1vxia5-jhqasdwc763s3pmb is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12784-d3k6aplejbvjrlcw-uwo81r0wkmeiptso is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12139-dpnhdmg2odfabvfn-zqgiw42wfsgbbkrc is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12137-dxtiqptvdwcrrcwa-22fkxorf6hl44evf is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12866-d37htmu48aopiafv-sli9m0lt3dz0yeyl is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12096-dz9pfno05wqq8vbg-sq8i5na5z8lrnm6n is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12363-dtlh9w3tza99quoj-dlicfndz6e3pbfu0 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12890-dmaaydjldw3c13jk-iskdygh5pczveo3r is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12320-dqmecms9nep6muns-xmmkziafa8mz1hta is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12936-dhdfa36ovcdzfafp-ultnlmom4scugsw1 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12964-dctbp9xgo2gl8w6i-kbw9cinhoieea8av is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12984-dwqjvkqc3aznhb4o-criyexpxvdndoscq is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12143-d3s1toagczaiq4ma-oupwnk3eg27r41ze is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13019-d5yrsi5a58bdzalc-i6mbum8zthk2arhs is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13022-djszrasae5w7xegh-ehqsutbhrwd7qgsi is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13027-dq6pg99jd2fphljg-u15x8sonbwukaree is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12041-dlsmtmfa6fp4wcuc-bfhftkdhwfqa7sqb is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13039-djtjimojqi3iaufp-csbinqtsvebzzmqx is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13061-duocptl9qdtvwubp-feryqeejht4j24ql is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13064-dexwkomdh62by80s-aymbuetu6p0btn4d is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13076-drd4nrhy4u7fq1tn-f1kt8ubk2jch4ol3 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13082-ds9gjikqyg9nftua-rrhk4dlrr8cp3la7 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12759-du4yducr4ghi8eun-bzivqxabwaltaddm is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12123-dzb9rktypp0jqinx-adtlzed02wpccxoa is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13118-d0lj9gpvqfmox63i-9jstjcjkmemszrla is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13121-du0r39n6wvnrclox-bviz76ig9vvexota is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13133-d2fk6lg6bsppbkcs-hwk5bmsvqxa0y0bs is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13204-dl6hzsmswetitsb4-bais6lpjbbhfkexn is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13230-dtiyrmijg8mde5xy-vobukov1qxg8bx5j is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13254-d3sdhrrgcvbwrsyp-yxaozxmt3clqzxxc is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13271-drutw4ihq774xhs6-ecpwfmzcrqy0vvsm is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13266-dmuj5cfeu2hrgfxw-2tpflycnwoedyidb is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13380-d99ciziibe7rt3es-7fkh56myy79oushw is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13487-d30yxx4wgfxcb9te-chc2bxojs7tvcwz3 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13502-dc2oivdodzo94jj3-1qmpba9ti4zzbfeg is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13277-deudjco25w9cd3rv-re1ha5qkozses9i3 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12208-dfqhoqmtuwzktwqm-n9s5daovhtnyvyeh is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13481-dthcwgpolombhfed-dkmesvsvmt1vem0d is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13585-ddvwhm2vcqpq66uy-1brs98bctgr6bcq9 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13586-dadacaexxn8nkuy3-fyx8zp5mursbqhns is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13587-dc0fmskwdbkmz7mg-ra53wgfksiv7tsqk is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13569-dk6v0pyvz8eoohl5-qyndiwn8zriir75s is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13603-d66mz2amabmd63fj-rkcqmtvfnlfmywou is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13613-dykuo32mnkgf9nce-hhkhn118dhsedoc8 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13623-dksoizdtoglihaax-23o0zltutliyoo2q is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13629-dxbpqqernfvufxrz-iv6jujdxm78hxjbn is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13610-drrehnh36oipacdf-frnumdhlt823mntg is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13654-dmlnhhqilztxff5a-4gawkysgtkze4st7 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13669-dk3ukgidvj0l4x4x-9d3vfao5qejzecdn is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13672-d1r1608gu96b0ujo-nn7ejmxkbfce40m4 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13689-dhpzh8w7jlwi0zza-aqizb6tbeuk9k1ca is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12477-dejmu0gihtllnj97-gaxwgicndwp25unx is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13710-dv2bktawped5fz44-0bkdtrkp8tk2vynu is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12125-d5d9pebts1rue7jt-vwnkapewjkfszked is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13718-dmimkn9h1ax3t4am-8tdnpznya2reek8g is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13545-dzaq2rjqfiyf5azl-kw35xomndhltjnrs is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13723-daleipfjwu7zm7aj-s8jo6yhxwz4efl2y is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13726-dpdqvmnzkvxkiz4y-cfudhed6m12hnlmj is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12136-d0qvvamyx5qq1g6o-awtlh6pbotvlacyc is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13258-du2kuwgkwhypcfzz-i6h00rd0exzw4b69 is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13755-dqglblzy3akyohph-wtev5tlrs5lkkejd is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13758-dhfrybljxildcky1-ktotkou3mpvxfjnq is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13759-dxqbq7phpjgoa1ed-dwtly1dkuorvlyli is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13762-di54bo3us4p8gefa-34s2uhcye1rbdbvw is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13767-dwtsyqxhqbp8fa9w-us8xvwm9q6nqkmzx is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13768-dadnlkrau2cwhlbd-cj8liz4hfolpmjfa is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13769-dt4nwlcmpfqyenob-jvpfd5jut8kvcm8u is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv13781-dvckr0uqfwrsvmc6-zklf1olhlhzzfppp is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12133-dp55dttaolpbd6n8-rlhoezgituqkyrov is not active
      vg_kvm/vsv12042-dnncyzlyhfxyaxkt-metx0ei0zlz3d2sn is not active
      vg_kvm/lvpool is not active
      vg_kvm/lvpool_tmeta is not active
      vg_kvm/lvpool_tdata is not active
      Locking LV i3usZzvdt59yaUKbclXDWJOFr1UhZRBaDHqs7X95DAADNmWTd9cXDfHR5aMoHLRx (EX)
    activation/volume_list configuration setting not defined: Checking only host tags for vg_kvm/lvpool.
      /dev/sda4: read_ahead is 256 sectors
      Getting driver version
      Getting target version for thin-pool
      Found thin-pool target v1.21.0.
      Getting target version for thin-pool
      Found thin-pool target v1.21.0.
      Getting target version for linear
      Found linear target v1.3.0.
      Getting target version for striped
      Found striped target v1.6.0.
    Creating vg_kvm-lvpool_tmeta
    Loading table for vg_kvm-lvpool_tmeta (253:0).
    Resuming vg_kvm-lvpool_tmeta (253:0).
    Creating vg_kvm-lvpool_tdata
    Loading table for vg_kvm-lvpool_tdata (253:1).
    Resuming vg_kvm-lvpool_tdata (253:1).
      global/thin_check_executable not found in config: defaulting to /usr/sbin/thin_check
      global/thin_check_options not found in config: defaulting to thin_check_options = [ "-q", "--clear-needs-check-flag" ]
    Executing: /usr/sbin/thin_check -q --clear-needs-check-flag /dev/mapper/vg_kvm-lvpool_tmeta
    /usr/sbin/thin_check failed: 1
  Check of pool vg_kvm/lvpool failed (status:1). Manual repair required!
    Removing vg_kvm-lvpool_tdata (253:1)
    Removing vg_kvm-lvpool_tmeta (253:0)
      Unlocking /run/lock/lvm/A_vg_kvm
      Unlocking /run/lock/lvm/V_vg_kvm
```

Comment: As a side note: You placed an answer to your question. Stack Exchange sites aren't like a forum where you post below you original post. New findings should be added to the original question, by editing. Also when asked for clarification in the comments, the information asked for can be provided by editing the original question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new :) Also, I couldn't add this as an edit because I used too many characters.

Comment: any suggestions regarding "  Check of pool vg_kvm/lvpool failed (status:1). Manual repair required!"

Comment: You can edit the original question. You should have plentry of characters there? Anyway, I commented to your original question, about the thin_check command.

Answer (score 1):

You can wipe the first 2k of the PV with the error before restoring your VG meta backup.  The default metadatasize of LVM is 1MB, so this shouldn't reach your data.  The dd will invalidate the header so LVM will think its an empty disk, then you can restore the PV and VG without it complaining about the state of the existing (invalid) PV/VG meta:

```
~]# dd if=/dev/zero bs=1k count=2 of=/dev/sdX
~]# sync # force to disk, LVM might use directio
~]# pvcreate -ff --uuid 06kvOm-xN2Y-iX1y-Tt69-LfFh-ltkG-TtRsgy --restorefile data /dev/bcache0
  Physical volume "/dev/sdX" successfully created.
~]# vgcfgrestore --force data
  Restored volume group data
```

It worked for me, be careful with the `dd` command!